# How to remove duplicates in power BI grouping by a particular column?

Tags: powerbi, duplicates, columnsorting

I have a dataset in the following manner:

[image]

I want to remove duplicate timestamps for each 'id' such that for each timestamp the value of 'revision' is the highest, i.e, the final dataset should look like this:

[image]

I want to do this in the query editor of power BI. I have tried doing this for one particular 'id' and it works. I selected id=1001, then I sorted revision in **descending order** and added an **index column** in the table. Then I applied '**remove duplicates**' on the timestamp column. This process works for one value of 'id'. I want to do this separately for each id such that I have each timestamp occur only once for any particular 'id'.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In power query, you can use the "group by" feature, with some modification, to accomplish this.  Here is the step you will need to add to do this:

```
= Table.Group(#"Previous Step", {"timestamp", "id"}, {{"revision", each List.Max([revision]), type nullable number}, {"value", each Table.Max(_, "revision")[value]}})
```

This is essentially telling power query to take the highest revision for each timestamp and id combination, and to also return the corresponding value.

Here is a detailed blog post of how this code works: https://www.ehansalytics.com/blog/2020/7/16/return-row-based-on-max-value-from-one-column-when-grouping

After sorting, here are the results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in the query editor itself. The trick is to select multiple columns at once while removing duplicates. So, I selected both 'id' and 'timestamp' and then applied 'remove duplicates'. Here, [1001 2022-05-02] will be different from [1002 2022-05-02], so it removes duplicate timestamps for different ids at once.